# Why the reversed-order terminology for paleocene/eocene and eoarchean/paleoarchean?

Tags: earth-history, terminology, time

I just learned that the [eoarchean era](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Eoarchean) comes right before the [paleoarchean era](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Paleoarchean), whereas the [paleocene epoch](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Paleocene) comes right before the [eocene epoch](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Eocene). This is quite confusing. Is there any sense behind this (seemingly inconsistent) terminology, or is it just due to historical accidents?